# How to ignore model binding from querystring in MVC

Tags: c#, .net, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-2, model-binding

I have form submission doing a post back.  The controller action accepts the values as parameters.  For ex: EditProduct(int productid, string productname).

productid is supplied from the form in a hidden field.  How can I ensure that that a user 
will not invoke this action and pass this productid and name as  queystring and the model binding will bind the vales and product is saved in database?

Comment: What makes you think the the user can't edit your hidden field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sign the product ID with a secret key on your server (using HMACSHA512), then verify the signature in the postback.

You might want to include the current date and/or the user or session ID when signing to prevent replay attacks.

Comment: Thanks.  This works but seems a bit of work.Is there any filters I can create or options so that I can specify to ignore any binding from querystring?

Answer (score 3):

I've found that the most secure approach would be to check that the user has permission to edit the product. Check this before you do any database updates in the action and you won't need to worry about users that modify the hidden values.

If you want to force users to go to your webpage to execute the post, you can use [Html.AntiForgeryToekn()](http://davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2009/04/29/AntiForgeryTokenInMVCFramework.aspx). However, a user can still visit the website, see the anti forgery token and pass it in with their request.

Answer (score 1):

You should implement proper access controls in the `EditProducts` action so that attempting to edit a different product will generate an error.

Trying to prevent users from modifying the querystring *won't help*.

Comment: If this was a classic asp.net application, I would use a link button which would post back the values and not worry about any cheating right?  I would not check if they had the rights to edit as it was all done and presented.   I would just go edit.

Comment: @Matt: **Totally wrong**.  Anyone can edit hidden fields.  If you have WebForms applications that do that, you should go back and fix them, right now.

Comment: omg...I just modified a hidden element and it submitte with the new value.  Our app is so screwed up right now. Thanks for the inputs.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you add a rowversion (timestamp) column to your model. That is a lot easier (if you can make changes to the model) than signing or hashing.

Comment: Thanks Peter.  I am not sure if I followed the solution.  How does adding a timestamp help prevent a user from calling editproducts?productid="123"&name="xyz" when the user was never supposed to access this  record.

Comment: @Matt - it isn't clear from your question that you are attempting to restrict access to the item. I interpreted your question to mean that you thought the user would be able to update the item by changing the query string. Please edit your question for clarity.

Comment: The idea is that only a few products filtered by access is presented to user in the GUI and they can only edit those.  So any authorized user can call editproducts by invoking the action and pass any valid id (with a good guess) in the query string and edit the product.  This needs to be prevented so that users cannot supply the info from query string but is submitted by only form collection to the modal binding